# Scrolling to bottom of UITableView (UITableView is in a UITableViewCell)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

How do I scroll all the way to the bottom of a UITableView when it is done loading?

The UITableView is located in a UITableViewCell and the UITableViewCell is located in a UItableView itself.

So:
UITableView --> UITableViewCell --> UITableView (scroll to the bottom here)

This is crashing:

```
func reloadData(){
    if (neighbourhoodJoined){
        messageInputView.hidden = false
        chatroomMessagesListReversed = chatroomMessagesList.reverse() as! [ChatroomMessage]
        chatroomTableView.reloadData()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            var iPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.chatroomTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)-1,
                inSection: self.chatroomTableView.numberOfSections-1)
            self.chatroomTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(iPath,
                atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom,
                animated: true)
        })
    } 
}
```

Comment: `tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height), animated: true)`

Comment: If I add that my that it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom and my PullToRefresh function gets called upon loading.

Answer (score 0):

you can like this:

```
if (tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height)
{
  tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height), animated: true)
}
```